# Plus character in question title

Tags: support, title, superuser

Why the "+" character in the question title in superuser.com causes the message saying "This post does not meet our quality standards" when trying to post? Is this behavior documented somewhere? I've just spent 10 minutes trying to figure out what's wrong with my question.

Comment: What was the title that you were trying ?

Comment: Titles are supposed to have more than a single character

Comment: It was more then a single character, "Alt + Arrows keys"

Comment: Was it a title only? Did you have anything at all in the question body?

Comment: Yes I have. http://superuser.com/questions/585221/alt-and-arrows-keys

Comment: @Soonts: My dear that title is terrible, good thing it got blocked. On the other hand, not hard enough.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really "+" that's hurting you there. It's that there wasn't much else to your title *beyond* "+". See [random's edit](https://superuser.com/revisions/585221/2) - that's what your title *should* have been: a short summary of the question you were asking.

You're allowed 150 characters for titles. Don't be afraid to use 'em next time...

Comment: The problem went away after I've changed "Alt + Arrows keys" to "Alt and Arrows keys" so I concluded it's the '+'. Now I understand you have a minimum title length. OK. The problem is - why didn't you tell me so? It took me 10 minutes and 4 edits to figure out what was wrong with my question (my #1 suggestion was the "damn" word, #2 was ♦♠ characters in the body, I don't already remember what were my other guesses). It's awful UX to tell user "sorry we don't like your data", without even a link to the spec containing your quality standards.

Comment: The hard *minimum* length is 15 characters, @Soonts - but in practice, titles not much longer than that are frequently pretty bad too (in part because folks who can't think of 15 characters to write tend to just throw nonsense in to pad them out). Beyond that, the quality check is more than just a length check: it also factors in capitalization, punctuation, common misspellings, etc. - with the end result of short titles being held to a higher standard than a longer one. We could've done better in this case by returning a message like, "This *title* does not meet our quality standards".

Comment: Yep - "This title does not meet our quality standards" would definitely help me, reducing 10 minutes to 1. Thanks in advance! :-)